# See-through vs transparent

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, usage

I know that 'see-through' means transparent.

Is There any differences in their usage?

Is 'see-through' the childish way to say 'transparent'?

Comment: "Is 'see-through' the childish way to say 'transparent'?" - to a certain extent, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"See-through" is specific to clothing.  You can say "She was wearing a see-through vest"  It means a vest made of thin fabric.  It might not be fully transparent, but it is thin enough that you can see whatever is underneath it. A synonym is "sheer".  Lace, gauze, netting... are all see-through fabrics.

It would be rather unusual to use "see-through" in other contexts, though it is possible in contexts in which there is an object that is usually opaque, but which has been designed as partially transparent. "Samsung release see-through phone"

It would be correct, to say "The window is transparent".  It would be odd to say "The window is see-through". Since windows are not normally opaque.

Comment: One little homonym error: “shear” vs “sheer”

Comment: "see-through" implies that you want to see what's there. "transparent" is just the quality of some material.